# How to get deleted data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find deleted data from table in my SQL Server on a particular date like 17 JUNE 2012 (27/06/2012).

Is there any query which will provide this result?

Comment: Do you have a backup from before the data was deleted?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: @Tsukasa That's great, but the question is tagged with SQL Server and the OP also mentions SQL Server in his question.

Comment: Do you have FULL transaction logs from then?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu oh sorry I saw 'my SQL' and registered it wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup from before the delete, then you will need to restore it.

There are some recovery tools out there using transaction logs, but they aren't cheap (there are some with trials) and I'm not sure if it works on logs from before installing the tool. It also may require that the delete happened in a transaction. If it didn't then the data is probably gone.

i.e.
http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

It's not helpful now, but the moral here is: Use transactions when deleting anything, and do backups regularly.